# How to set size for variable length datatype

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

I am working on sending parameters to a procedure and do some operations based on the output returned from the procedure. I have a common class that handles adding parameters and calling the procedure. The class will be called like:

```cs
obj.addparameter(parametername, parametervalue, oracletype.datatype, parameterdirection.input)
```

so lets say i have a procedure that takes customer id as parameter and outputs name.

```sql
PROCEDURE get_customer_name(
c_customer_id IN Number,
c_customer_name OUT VARCHAR)
IS
BEGIN
 SELECT last_name || ' ' || middle_name  || ' ' || first_name  
 INTO c_customer_name
 FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = c_customer_id;
END;
```

To call the above procedure i need to call the class like:

```cs
 obj.addparameter("customerId", 123, oracletype.number, parameterdirection.Input)
 obj.addparameter("customerName", dbnull.value, oracletype.varchar, parameterdirection.output)
```

The class has  the following code:

```cs
if (param.ParamDirection == ParameterDirection.Output)
{
    command.Parameters.Add(c_customer_name,oracletype.varchar);
    command.parameters["c_customer_name"].direction = parameterdirection.output                                                                    
}
else
{
    command.parameters.add("c_customer_id",oracletype.number).value = 123;
    command.parameters["c_customer_id"].direction = parameterdirection.input
}
command.commandType = commandType.StoredProcedure;
command.executenonquery();//Error: c_customer_name "No size set for  variable length data type: String."
```

When I run the above code, I am getting an error:

> "No size set for variable length data type: String."

I had to add the size of the column in the line below to avoid the error.

```cs
command.Parameters.Add(c_customer_name,oracletype.varchar,50)//Add size to output parameter
```

Is there a way to avoid adding size property to output parameter. [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleparameter.size%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it looks like size property needs to be added for output parameters. If thats the case then,how to handle the size for different output parameters. I might return "customer name", "address" as parameters but I don't want to specify size for different output parameters.
I am working on .NET4.0 with C# code-behind and Oracle database.

Comment: May be varchar(max) in db and client code will you?

Comment: @lavrik - I tried to set size in procedure but still it looks like i need to assign a value in C# code.

Comment: So try to add the max possible length, i suppose you have some validation rules over customer name, specifying  the max length.

Comment: If you have access to the DBA views and know the table name and field name you should be able to query DBA_TAB_COLS to get the declared size of the field.